# Unity 2D Physics Collision Detection Not Working Exactly

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies, collider

I am making a kind of pinball game for learning purpose. Whenever the ball hits the  flipper it passes through them. I have made the balls rigidbody2d detection set to continuous but it still isnt working.

Comment: Are you using a Collider for the flippers? If so, which one are you using?

Comment: It is also possible that if the collision boxes for your flippers are too slim and if your ball is moving fast enough, the pinball could be in front of the flipper one frame and behind the flipper the next frame (without either of them overlapping and triggering a collision)

Comment: does it work in general if the objects move slow? [Here](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/DontGoThroughThings) is a very old but maybe still valid workaround for this

Comment: @RippStudwell yes i was using polygon collider 2d first. When it didnt workout. I decided to use a box collider 2d but the result is still the same

Comment: Yes it works if the objects move slow @derHugo

Comment: What method are you using to rotate the flippers?

Comment: Im just rotating them in update on mouse button down as transfor.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3); @LeoBartkus

Comment: You should try using RigidBody.MoveRotation instead of setting the transform.localRotation.  And doing this in FixedUpdate instead of Update

Comment: @LeoBartkus brother you made my game more than perfect. It worked. Thank you for teaching me this new technique. I am very thankful to you and everybody else who tried to help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use RigidBody.MoveRotation instead of setting the transform.localRotation. And doing this in FixedUpdate instead of Update

Answer (score 0):

You should try using RigidBody.MoveRotation instead of setting the transform.localRotation. And doing this in FixedUpdate instead of Update – Leo Bartkus

Comment: You can request @Leo Bartkus to post his comment as answer and select it.

Comment: yupp didnt knew how to post that as answer